# How to make seo-friendly AMP page query string

Tags: seo, query-string, amp-html

I have an AMP page that accepts query string

https://example.com/page?id=123

I can get the value of id using QUERY_PARAM(id)

Now I want to pass the param using

https://example.com/page/123

How to access the value of the param (123) from AMP page?

Comment: "How to access the value of the param (123) from AMP page?" — Generally, this value is accessed via server-side code. The AMP is irrelevant and the answer depends entirely on which server-side programming language you are using.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:asynchronous-messaging-protocol] which doesn't seem to make any sense. Did you mean [tag:amp-html]? (Not that that seems relevant to the actual problem)

Comment: yes. amp-html. Already corrected it. Tq

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this variable in AMP just from URL (if it is not a query parameter).

The suggested way is to send the same from your server and use it in the amp-html template.